# Create projects with Phonegap 3.0

Tags: android, cordova, windows-runtime, cordova-3

I try to create 3 project with new new Phonegap Cordova 3.0 with WinRT / Android / iOS. I didn't understand the documentation and I can't find any tutorial.

I installed NodeJS and phonegap without error. Then, I try to create the Android app first with these lines:

```
 $ phonegap create my-app
 $ cd my-app
 $ phonegap run android
```

I guess the "run android" generate an apk and it's not necessary to have a Android Eclipse project. But the command line stop at "Detecting Android SDK Environment" so I tried this command:

```
$ phonegap -V run android
```

And now the Detecting Android SDK Environment pass, but it block at Running "android list target".

So I tried to create an WinRT app but apparently we have to create our own WinRT project first and then "deploy" phonegap into it. But how the code can be synchronised with the Android and iOS project?

If someone have a complete tutorial with phonegap 3.0 I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)? The new beta version has support for phonegap applications. [Here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB74#PhoneGap) is where you can start.

Comment: Thanks for this information it can really helpfull, but when I try to create the Phonegap project netbeans ask me the Phonegap SDK location and I can find it (Before with Phonegap 2.X there was zip file, and if I put my phonegap 2.9 files it works but I need the 3.0)

Comment: yep, @Podelo its all very confusing, i'm struggling away myself!

Answer (score 1):

The "phonegap create my-app" syntax is incorrect. It should be: "phonegap create AAA com.myproject MyProject"

This creates a folder called AAA and places the PhoneGap files in there.

Comment: Thanks for this tutotial but my CLI still block at "detecting XXX SDK environment" (XXX can be Android, wp7 ...) and you don't have this error in your tutorial

Comment: @Steve: the syntax is correct. just the first parameter after create is mandatory.